# popup menu in ionic3 along with label field and confirm button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I created Ionic3 project

In that I have a two buttons `email` button and `confirm email` button

Here I need a help

When User click `email` button then it will need to show popup with label fied along with `confirm`button

Comment: Great, all you have to do now is make it yourself. And if you face an issue, come back here with a [mcve] or at least some code. [ask] might help you, too.

Comment: confirm email have no responsibility....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In `.html`**

```
<button ion-button block (click)="showPopUp()">email</button>
<button ion-button block >confirm email</button>
```

**In `.ts` file first need to inject `AlertController` in `constructor`**

```
constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController)

showPopUp() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Popup',
        buttons: [{
        text: 'Confirm',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('confirm click');
        }
      }]
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

Further details for popup [show popup official link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/)